# How to allow double click selection of strings with - in them, within Atom?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, atom-editor, text-editor

Say I have a string like `'cheap-module-inline-source-map'` in the following:

[image]

In **[Atom](https://atom.io/)**, I want to be able to just double click that string to select the entire string. However it only let's me select the words I click on.

I did find the following in Settings > Editor:

[image]

Originally it was `/\()"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}?-…`

I removed the `-` however this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you close/open the window after changing that setting? I occasionally find settings in Atom that don't refresh the behavior of already-open windows/buffers.

Comment: @DanLowe Yeah I totally restarted several times :( still won't let me select and entire string like `search-box-container`

Comment: FWIW many of the grammars (including Javascript) have their own non-word chars setting, try looking in that package and see if you have a specific setting that is overriding the global one. Settings -> packages -> language-javascript -> Settings

Comment: @DanLowe good to know! I just checked javascript and babel and they both have `/\()"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`?…` in there.. posting new screenshot.

Comment: @DanLowe That was it! Ok when I entered it in, it did not save correctly... I changed the string and now it saves correctly! Want to post your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already looked at the global settings (under "Editor"), but many settings (including this one) appear in the various packages so that you can customize things per syntax.

This setting seems to exist in both `language-javascript` and `language-babel`, and perhaps you have other Javascript packages that have it (there are many of them out there...)

If you navigate to...

- Settings
- Packages
- search for "javascript" or "babel"
- click "Settings" on the package

Then you will find a "Grammar" settings section in most syntax packages. This is the one from `language-javascript`.

[image: language-javascript settings panel]

As you can see it has a copy of the Non-Word Characters setting. You can set this explicitly, though I would have expected it to inherit from the global value.

`language-babel` has this too, though you need to scroll down a bit further to find it.